# Not able to display category link and name

Tags: categories

I bought a wordpress theme and I am not able to display the category link and name.

```
<div class="item-info">';
  if($show_aut!='0'){
      $author = get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );
      $html .='<span class="item-author"><a href="'.$author.'"title="'.get_the_author().'">'.get_the_author().'</a></span>';}

  //DISPLAY CATEGORY LINK AND NAME
  if($show_sub_aut!='0'){
      $subaut = get_the_category();
      $html .= '<span  class="item-sub-aut"><a href="'.$subaut.'" title="'.get_category_link().'">'.get_category_link().'</a></span>';}
  if($show_date!='0'){  
   $html .= '<span class="item-date">'.get_the_time(get_option('date_format')).'</span>';}                    
   $html .= '</div>
   </div>';
```

Comment: Hey Pieter, I cleaned the code. Can you take a look now. Thanks.

Comment: Much better, and much more readable. It really helps to properly indent code. It is easy to see the issue now without even looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_the_catgory()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) returns an array of category objects assigned to a post. You are trying to use the result as a string. If you have debugging enabled, you would have received an error regarding this.

You either need to loop through the array and handle each category separately, or you can reference them directly, like `get_the_category()[0]` would return the first category object

Lets say you would want to show only the first category, then the following line

```
$html .= '<span  class="item-sub-aut"><a href="'.$subaut.'" title="'.get_category_link().'">'.get_category_link().'</a></span>';
```

would become

```
$html .= '<span  class="item-sub-aut"><a href="'. esc_url( get_category_link ( $subaut[0] ) ) .'" title="'. $subaut[0]->name.'">' . $subaut[0]->name . '</a></span>';
```

### EDIT

If you need to display all the categories separated by a comma, you can do the following

```
$subaut = get_the_category();
foreach ( $subaut as $cat ) 
    $array[] = '<span  class="item-sub-aut"><a href="'. esc_url( get_category_link ( $cat ) ) .'" title="'. $cat->name.'">' . $cat->name . '</a></span>';

$html .= implode( ', ', $array );
```

Comment: You are a genius the code works great. I wish all the best and much success. Before I close I wanted to say a last thing, I have post that belong to 2 categories, but now it is displaying only one, how can I get to display all the categories separated by commas. Thanks.

Comment: Answer updated. It is untested though, but should work.

Comment: I get an Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$array' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Sorry, missed a `,` in the last line. I have updated the code. Should work now

Comment: Once again, thanks a lot. **I wish you all the best and much success. You are a genius.** Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure, glad everything worked out. Enjoy, and goodluck on your project ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Get the category return an array, use

```
 <?php 
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) { 
// print_r(cat);
} ?>
```

to get more detail about link and category name